# Comparing cookie values with page parameters (i.e. href)

Tags: web-browser, cookies

Could you suggest if there is any reason to compare cookie value domain, path, etc with web "location.href" and so on?
I mean - on the client side.

Comment: What are you trying to *do*?

Comment: I'm trying to build browser pluging to detect if there is any webpage which use cookies in wrong way.

Comment: Not clear enough what you are trying to do. Are you concerned about the `same origin policy`?

Comment: Yes, same origin policy but also to check and log if the cookies on current site use cookies properties in most secure way and if not - to let user know about it.

Answer (score 1):

No.  I don't know of any reason to perform that sort of check in a browser plug-in.  Web browsers will already perform same-origin checks for you.  But then, your question was pretty vague, so it's hard to know what exactly you might have in mind.

Generally speaking, I prefer to start by asking: What problem am I trying to solve?  Once you know what problem you're trying to solve, then you can start to talk about technical measures that might help.

Comment: I was wandering about the example: One browser with two tab. Both have the same website but different pages. What I didn't  know was: how to detect which page changed the cookie.

After reading your answer I realized - I should use just one tab during the test ;) 

Sometimes the simplest questions are the toughest. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I wish to verify if the domain and path has not been set too loosely:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_cookies_attributes_(OWASP-SM-002)#Black_Box_testing_and_example

Comment: @HolySync, I think there may have been some miscommunication or confusion here. (That would be understandable, as that OWASP page you linked to is not very clearly written.)  The OWASP page is talking about suggestions for testing a web application to see if it is using cookies in a safe way.  (It is *not* about testing whether the browser uses the same-origin policy correctly.  It is *not* about helping users of the web site: it is aimed at developers or pentesters.) For more on that, I suggest you start by reading about security testing of web applications. Then, ask a more focused question.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. The project is already finished. It still need some improvements but it works :)